# To Remove spaces before and after image in owl carousel

Tags: owl-carousel

If there is a image , it want to be align in center otherwise It should be align from the margin, I have a added options in owl carousel.Still it doesn't work.

Reference Code:

```
$('#inner-project-galler').owlCarousel({
        loop: false,

       center : true,
        autoplay:true,
        margin: 35,


        //nav: true,
        navText:["<div class='nav-btn prev-slide service-inner-arrow-prev'></div>","<div class='nav-btn next-slide service-inner-arrow-next'></div>"],
        responsive: {
            0: {
                items: 1

            },
            600: {
                items: 2
            },
            1000: {
                items: 3
            }
        }

    });
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6adq.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVazy.png)